# Check if a record has any attachment - Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I need to write a plugin where I have to check if a particular record has any file attached.

When I remove any file from a record it gets soft deleted.
I check Annotation table in SQL server, but is there any flag that denotes the entry is soft deleted or not?

Comment: AFAIK, CRM 2011 doesn't soft-delete anymore

Answer (score 2):

Dynamics CRM 2011 does not have a soft-delete. When the record is deleted in CRM there is a `DELETE` executed on the SQL server, resulting in the record being removed.

In an `annotation`, which is the entity for Note, an attachment is stored as bas64 encoded text. If you delete an attachment on a Note it results in an `UPDATE` to the `annotation` entity setting the fields related to the attachment to `null`.

If you want to trigger a plugin when an attachment is deleted you need to look at the both the delete and update events on `annotation`. If you want to know if the annotations related to a particular entity has an attachment you need to query `annotation` entity where `objectid` matches the entity and `filename` is not null.

For emails and appointments attachments are stored in `activitymimeattachment` instead of `annotation`.

Comment: Thanks, it helped

Comment: @PriyojitMondal You're welcome, if this is the correct answer please mark it as correct.